# How do I implement Facebook Connect alongside OpenID on my website?

Tags: php, openid, facebook

Right now I have a website that only accepts OpenIDs. Each user's account is associated with an OpenID identifier. How would I allow users to use Facebook Connect to login?

Are there any free, open-source client authentication libraries that abstract away the task of dealing with multiple services? I'm not looking for a service like RPX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look at these two websites:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web

http://mashable.com/2009/09/30/facebook-connect-wizard/